# Trouble adding filter to product collection via observer

Tags: product-attribute, product-collection, collection-filtering, magento-1.14

My goal is to filter the category product list by product's first letter. This works on my staging site by implementing the following:

1. /app/code/local/Etre/Alphapagination/etc/config.xml

   ```
       <catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after>
           <observers>
               <etre_alphapagination>
                   <type>model</type>
                   <class>etre_alphapagination/observer</class>
                   <method>applyFilter</method>
               </etre_alphapagination>
           </observers>
       </catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after>
   ```
2. /app/code/local/Etre/Alphapagination/Model/Observer.php

   ```
   <?php

   class Etre_Alphapagination_Model_Observer
   {
       public function insertPagination($observer)
       {
           /** @var $_block Mage_Core_Block_Abstract */
           /*Get block instance*/
           $_block = $observer->getBlock();
           /*get Block type*/
           $_type = $_block->getType();
           /*Check block type*/
           if ($_type == 'page/html_pager') {
               /*Clone block instance*/
               $_child = clone $_block;
               /*set another type for block*/
               $_child->setType('alphapagination/html_pager');
               /*set child for block*/
               $_block->setChild('originalPagination', $_child);
               /*set our template*/
               $_block->setTemplate('etre_alphapagination/alphapaginator.phtml');
           }
       }
       public function applyFilter($observer){

           if ($alphaFilter = Mage::getModel('etre_alphapagination/parametersactions')->currentAlphaFilter()) {
               $event = $observer->getEvent();
               $collection = Mage::getModel('etre_alphapagination/parametersactions')->applyFilter($event->getCollection(), $alphaFilter, "name");
               return $this;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The applyFilter function looks like this:

```
public function applyFilter($collection, $query="",$attribute = 'name') //let's provide the option to filter the collection by whichever attribute desired
{
    try {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => $query.'%'));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

The full code can be seen [here](https://github.com/tylerofathenry/Etre_Alphapagination).

Whenever I filter by a letter attribute counts are updated correctly but pagination is not and sometimes I get Magento's "there are no products matching this..." notice when there are results to be returned.

On my staging site the module works perfectly - but am having a hard time troubleshooting this on my live site.

Comment: Do you really expect `$collection->addAttributeToFilter(...)` to throw an exception? Looks a bit fishy to me ... sure not an answer to your question, just seeing it and it makes no sense to me.

Comment: How experienced should I be before I learn that addAttributeToFilter can't throw an exception? I am just hoping to catch an error if it occurs at that point.

In other words, what you're saying is the try/catch will serve no purpose here and can be removed. Got it.

Comment: Yes, and also: As you catch *any* **Exception** you will not notice that there was a problem. As you normally expect adding the attribute filter to work you actually *want* to learn about exceptions. The little-catch-try block so then hindered you to learn about problems. --- So I didn't say it can't throw an exception. Just that if it would, you would want to know about it (and it's also OK to halt the script then). If you remove it for example and an exception would happen on your live server, it would be logged to the `exception.log` and you then could read about it. Magento catches them 4U

Comment: As you can see, even I'm not experienced to know that addAttributeToFilter  can't throw an exception. I just use that method and I expect it to work. If it doesn't, either there is a bug and I need to investigate it or I did a mistake in using that method and then I need to investigate it as well ;)

Comment: Were you able to fix it @TylersSN